# SELECTED not working with <option> tag inside a for loop/ while loop

Tags: php

i want one of the options in drop down to be selected by default,  Please see the code

```
<?php
class html{

    function output(){

        $html='<td>'.'<select id="out">';
        for($i=0;$i<21;$i++){
            $html.='<option value="$i" if($i==5) { selected } >'. $i .'</option>';
        }

        return $html;
    }
}

echo html::output();
?>
```

Here i want value 5 to be selected by default,But I am getting selected value as 20.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: Programming does not work that way.

Comment: I did not follow you , Sorry Could you make it clear. What is problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're line is incorrect. Use this instead:

```
$html .= '<option value="' . $i . '"' . ( $i==5 ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' . $i . '</option>';
```

I'm making use of the [ternary comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 2):

Put your if condition out of quotes

```
for($i=0;$i<21;$i++)
{
   $selected=($i==5) ? 'selected' : '';
   $html.="<option value='$i'  $selected>". $i ."</option>";

}
```

Comment: Will fail due to improper quoting. May also be wrong depending on desired HTML version/adherence.

Comment: @ignacio: Where is the improper quotes?

Comment: You had the second line in single quotes before.

Comment: @ignacio: Oh, That was there with initial answer but improved immediately

Answer (score 1):

here is the problem

```
$html.='<option value="$i" if($i==5) { selected } >'. $i .'</option>';
```

SolutionL

```
$html.="<option value=\"$i\" ".($i==5? "selected": ""). "$i </option>";
```